Error TS2769 en TypeScript con Express y Express-Fileupload
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Node.js utilizando TypeScript, Express y express-fileupload. Me he encontrado con un error persistente que no he podido resolver y espero que alguien pueda ayudarme. Llevo un día intentando solucionarlo sin éxito. Estoy extendiendo la interfaz Request de Express para incluir la propiedad files de express-fileupload. Al intentar definir una ruta POST para subir y procesar imágenes, obtengo el siguiente error:TS2769: No overload matches this call.
El error sale justo en el procesador del escaner, que es justamente lo que necesito que la APP haga bien, y también tengo el archivo typescript de extensión d.ts,
En serio necesito  su ayuda, estaré muy agradecida.
Codigo
import { UploadedFile } from "express-fileupload";
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      files?: {
        [key: string]: UploadedFile | UploadedFile[];
      };
    }
  }
}

import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import mysql from "mysql";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import path from "path";
import fileUpload, { UploadedFile } from "express-fileupload";
import Tesseract from "tesseract.js";

interface CustomRequest extends Request {
  files?: fileUpload.FileArray;
}

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public")));
app.use(fileUpload()); // Asegúrate de que fileUpload está configurado aquí

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "USUARIO",
  password: "CLAVE",
  database: "inventario_db",
});

db.connect((err: mysql.MysqlError) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Conectado a la base de datos MySQL");
});

app.post("/api/productos", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const {
    Barcode,
    DescriptionProduct,
    NP,
    Stockroom,
    BinLocation,
    Remarks,
    EntryDate,
  } = req.body;

  const sql =
    "INSERT INTO productos (Barcode, ProductName, PartNumber, Stockroom, BinLocation, Remarks, EntryDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  const values = [
    Barcode,
    DescriptionProduct,
    NP,
    Stockroom,
    BinLocation,
    Remarks,
    EntryDate,
  ];

  db.query(sql, values, (err: mysql.MysqlError | null) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send("Producto registrado exitosamente");
  });
});

app.get("/api/productos/:barcode", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const barcode = req.params.barcode;
  const sql = "SELECT ProductName, PartNumber FROM productos WHERE Barcode = ?";
  db.query(sql, [barcode], (err: mysql.MysqlError | null, results: any) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (results.length > 0) {
      res.json(results[0]);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send("Producto no encontrado");
    }
  });
});

app.post("/scan-image", (req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
  }

  const imageFile = req.files.image as UploadedFile;
  Tesseract.recognize(imageFile.data, "eng", {
    logger: (m) => console.log(m),
  })
    .then(({ data: { text } }) => {
      console.log(text);
      res.send({ text });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("ERROR:", err);
      res.status(500).send("Error processing image.");
    });
});

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "public", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:3000");
});


En que linea te sale el error?

app.post('/scan-image', (req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => {

En la linea 73 , he intentado todo,

es especificamente en este fragmento de codigo: (req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => {

No overload matches this call significa que enrealidad alguno de los parametros del metodo contiene una sobrecarga invalida, en este caso, segun lo que mencionas se trata del metodo scan-image, seguramente posees parametros incorrectos o te falta alguno, o quizas la estructura de datos no es la que requiere ninguno de los dos parametros, inclusive la respuesta puede ser una pendejada como que simplemente estas añadiendo mas parametros que no necesitas.
Por lo tanto lo que te recomiendo es que busques en la documentacion cuales son los parametros adecuados o cual es la sobrecarga adecuada

Pienso que estas trabajando con la versión 5.0.0 de @types/express. Los tipos de esta ultima versión actualmente no están funcionando con la última versión de express
Mi solución recomendada seria installar la versión anterior de types express:
npm install -D @types/express@4.17.21
Otra solución es que tambien puedes optar por usar un return void:
app.post("/scan-image", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
    res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
    return 
  }

  const imageFile = req.files!.image as UploadedFile; // files! ya que puede ser null o undefined como se especificó en el archivo .d.ts

Por otro lado, observando el código, no es necesario definir el CustomRequest. La propiedad files ya es de tipo de dato FileArray y su propiedad image proveniente del name del input será de tipo UploadedFile
